# Calculate angles from 3d skeleton points for BVH file

Tags: rotation, linear-algebra, blender, mo-cap

I am trying to calculate the Euler angles to put into a BVH file, from a sequence of 3d points for each joint. I have created the Hierarchy of the file and the Offsets, but I am having trouble successfully calculating the angles. I am currently trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243446/how-to-get-rotationeuler-angle-between-two-3d-vectors-to-make-bvh-format) post, but it is producing incorrect angles.

Anyone know the formula or a way to calculate Euler angles for BVH files from 3d joint coordinates? Thank you, any help is appreciated.